# Why wont JRE run my .Jar file

Tags: java, minecraft, jre, jar

Before you mark this as the same thing as the others, You need to know I have done this before hundreds of times with no problem, I just reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 2 days ago, and I was trying something with Minecraft and tried to open the optifine download, which is a jar file, and it wont do anything I tried running it in terminal and this is what I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper`
```

I had installed Java the same as I always had no problems, but this time is different. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the `openjdk-8-jre`? If you have `openjdk-11-jre` or similar installed, you're going to have a lot of breakages for Optifine and Minecraft.

Comment: I got it to work. I had jdk 11 on it and I think it was conflicting with 8. I just remove everything involving java and reinstalled and it worked

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped! (I had the same issues myself, so I figured I wasn't alone.)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the assistive technology may do the trick :

`sh
sudo sed -i "s/^assistive_technologies=/#&/" \
/etc/java-11-openjdk/accessibility.properties`

Remark : use the right property file for your config, here it is for openjdk v11.

Comment: It just started crashing on startup, So now I think disabling broke it. Minecraft Runs without it though, so its not the game, Its Java i think

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the atk wrapper to the classpath

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/java-atk-wrapper.jar
```

Comment: Not deleting this answer because it is listed as a workaround on the openjdk bug and does work for some instances of the atk wrapper bug, so it's worth remaining for some people that hit this page.